# OBS-Websocket change source text and image

Tags: python, websocket, obs

I am trying to edit the text of an obs source, as well as an image.
I don't get any errors and I am able to switch scenes using
`ws.call(requests.SetCurrentProgramScene(sceneName=scene_name))`,
so my WebSocket connection works.

I am using OBS 30 with the integrated WebSocket and the `obs-websocket-py` package.

This is my full code:

```
from obswebsocket import obsws, requests

new_image_file_path = "image.png"
source_name_text = "text"
source_name_image = "image"

def connect():
    host = "localhost"
    port = 4455
    password = "myPassword"
    ws = obsws(host, port, password)
    ws.connect()

    run(ws)

def run(ws):

    request = requests.SetSourceSettings(
        sourceName=source_name_image,
        sourceSettings={"file": new_image_file_path}
    )
    ws.call(request)

    ws.call(requests.SetTextGDIPlusProperties(
        source_name=source_name_text,
        text="text"
    ))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connect()
```

I checked, if the connection to the WebSocket works and it does.
I tried using different variations I could find, but non of them were any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those requests are for WebSocket plugin version 4.

OBS 28 and newer, comes with builtin WebSocket plugin version 5, where `SetSourceSettings` and `SetTextGDIPlusProperties` requests don't exist anymore.
They were replaced with `SetInputSettings`.

This is the new way of doing it:

```
ws.call(requests.SetInputSettings(
    inputName=source_name_image,
    inputSettings={
        "file": new_image_file_path,
    }
))

ws.call(requests.SetInputSettings(
    inputName=source_name_text,
    inputSettings={
        "text": "text",
    }
))
```

Comment: What would the code be for enabling the visibility of a source? I'm struggling to find the solution for that